# Query regarding my rating system

Tags: php, cookies, system, rating

I have built a rating system where a user can thumbs up/down a blog. There is no login system ( must stay like this too). So therefore, in order to stop the user voting more then once, i wish to use cookies ( not sessions, as they are destroyed when browsers closes). However i have read the PHP manual and it states that all cookies must be created before the HTML tag.. This makes no sense to me, because how am i meant to create cookies and assign data to it that is only acquired deeper in the page (after html tag), take a look at my code:

```
            print "<img src=\"/images/up.png\" onclick=\"increase_rating()\">";
            print "<img src=\"/images/down.png\" onclick=\"decrease_rating()\">";
```

Now i wish to create something where, once a user clicks an image, it creates a cookie with the choice(ie, rated up or down) and also the id of the blog they voted on(so multiple blogs could be voted)..So if the user reloads the page they wouldnt be able to vote because a cookie would be set.

**What I mean(this obviously wont work, its almost my idea(pseudo-code):**
Its basically saying, if its already been clicked(cookie has been set), then dont let them increment a rating or decrease its rating, by not running the function that does it.

```
        if ($_COOKIE['up_clicked']){
            print "<img src=\"/images/up.png\" >";
            print "<img src=\"/images/down.png\">";
        }elseif ($_COOKIE['down_clicked']){
            print "<img src=\"/images/up.png\" >";
            print "<img src=\"/images/down.png\">"; 
        }else{
        // if nothing is clicked
            print "<img src=\"/images/up.png\" onclick=\"increase_rating()\">";
            print "<img src=\"/images/down.png\" onclick=\"decrease_rating()\">";
        }
```

Can someone help  me out? Thanks

Comment: For readers, there is [another related question from the OP here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240209/how-to-add-ajax-to-a-thumbs-up-down-rating-system-using-pure-javascript).

Comment: The only relevance is that its the same project, which matters not in terms of answering a generic question such as this.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use JavaScript to manage cookies. PHP is a Hypertext Preprocessor, which means code is executed before the HTML view is fully rendered.

To do this you will need to bind a click event to your up and down vote buttons. Easiest way is to use jQuery, and jQuery Cookies plugin, which can be found here:

jQuery: http://jquery.com/

jQuery Cookie plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

A short example:

```
$("#upvote").click(function(e){
     //prevent default click behavior
     e.preventDefault();
     //Check if cookie exists
     var cookie = $.cookie('the_cookie');
     if(cookie){
         //don't do anything already upvoted
        return false;
     }else {
        //get ID i usually put it in a rel="<?=$id?>" field on a link via php
        var id = $(this).attr("rel");
        var url = "http://example.com/php-script-to-increase-vote-by-one";
        //up vote article
        $.post(url, id);
        //create cookie valid for a year for entire site
        $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 365, path: '/' });
     }
 });
```

Obviously it should be noted that if the user isn't logging into a system, a user can clear their cookies, and upvote something as much as they want.